# Raise error during bulk POST if an index document with identical _id already exists?

Tags: elasticsearch

I can see that for non-bulk PUT operations this functionality exists, for the `_id` field, using "op_type" [as explained in the API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html).

So I tried this URL:

`https://localhost:9200/my_index/_bulk/?op_type=create`

and also

`https://localhost:9200/my_index/_bulk?op_type=create`

Both failed:

```
"error": {
    "reason": "request [/my_index/_bulk/] contains unrecognized parameter: [op_type]",
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? The request body is the bulk string itself and the method is POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `create` instead of `index` in `_bulk`

```
DELETE test

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"create": {"_id": "foo"}}
{"test": 1}
{"create": {"_id": "foo"}}
{"test": 2}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```